# Get JavaScript array from page to Python using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a page which has a script and it contains one array which I need (myHashDay).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleCheckBoxes(obj) {
        var theForm = document.getElementById("thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm");
        for (var i=0; i<theForm.elements.length; i++) {
            if (theForm.elements[i].type == "checkbox" &&
                theForm.elements[i].name != obj.name) {

                theForm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // ATLAS-1089: back & continue buttons showing twice for
    //             Reserved Group/Emergency Appointments
    function checkIfButtonsShowTwice() {

        // From first form
        var continueBtn = document.getElementById("thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm:continueBtn");
        var backBtn = document.getElementById("thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm:backBtn");

        // From second form
        var continueBtnToHide = document.getElementById("thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm2:continueBtn");
        var backBtnToHide = document.getElementById("thePage:SiteTemplate:theForm2:form2BackBtn");

        // The controller logic for rendering the buttons
        // is fragile so... front end solutions for the win
        if(continueBtn != null) {
            if (continueBtnToHide != null) {
                continueBtnToHide.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    var myDayHash = new Array();
    myDayHash['14-9-2023'] = true;
    myDayHash['4-12-2023'] = true;
    myDayHash['31-1-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['1-2-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['27-2-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['28-2-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['4-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['5-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['6-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['7-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['11-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['12-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['13-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['14-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['18-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['19-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['20-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['21-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['25-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['26-3-2024'] = true;
    myDayHash['27-3-2024'] = true;

    var ofcAptDateStr = null;ofcAptDateStr = '';

    var splitDate = 'Thu Sep 14 00:00:00 GMT 2023'.split(" ");
    var minApptDate = splitDate[1] + ' ' + splitDate[2] + ' ' + splitDate[5];
}
</script>
```

So I need to get myDayHash array from it.

What I am trying to do:

```
driver.get('\test.html')
element = driver.execute_script("myDayHash")
```

But it doesn’t return anything.

I tried element = driver.execute_script("return myDayHash") as well. But it returns none.

But if I use the console in the Chrome browser and type "myDayHash" it prints my whole array.

How can I get this array to Python?

Comment: you should have some API written for that ...

Comment: wut? why do i need api for such purpose? I just need to get array data from webpage (html contains this array)

Comment: To get something on backend you may require a simple API, okay any other alternatives I would be happy to learn too

Comment: Its not an backend. html source contains this js func and array. i can accsess it by using Chrome dev console easilly

Comment: do you need the `myDayHash` array? You can parse the script text to get the same

Comment: or execute this function `checkIfButtonsShowTwice` and fetch the  `myDayHash` array

Comment: @Himanshuman but how to parse? using regex?

Comment: @kappa yes! Would it possible to share the link of website or is it private?

Comment: okay, selenium thing I'm not aware of ... thanks

Comment: Can you post your exact expected output please

Comment: @Himanshuman here is what i need https://prnt.sc/tiKtmqGyMTnl

Comment: So i just need simply get full array with data into python. Thats it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup) and [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

##### Fetch the data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://website.com/test.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
array = soup.select('script')
```

##### Get the text from each script tag

```
text = ' '.join([elem.text for elem in array])
```

##### Apply regex to get myDayHash

The below regex gives you the `myDayHash` datastructure values in the form of list of tuples.

```
myDayHash = re.findall(r"myDayHash\[\'(.*?)\'\] = (.*?);", text)
```

##### Generating output:

```
print(dict(myDayHash))
```

##### Output

This gives us the expected output. Now based on your requirement, you can store the key:value pair into any data structure.

```
{
    '14-9-2023': 'true',
    '4-12-2023': 'true',
    '31-1-2024': 'true',
    '1-2-2024': 'true',
    '27-2-2024': 'true',
    '28-2-2024': 'true',
    '4-3-2024': 'true',
    '5-3-2024': 'true',
    '6-3-2024': 'true',
    '7-3-2024': 'true',
    '11-3-2024': 'true',
    '12-3-2024': 'true',
    '13-3-2024': 'true',
    '14-3-2024': 'true',
    '18-3-2024': 'true',
    '19-3-2024': 'true',
    '20-3-2024': 'true',
    '21-3-2024': 'true',
    '25-3-2024': 'true',
    '26-3-2024': 'true',
    '27-3-2024': 'true'
}
```

### TLDR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://website.com/test.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
array = soup.select('script')
text = ' '.join([elem.text for elem in array])
myDayHash = re.findall(r"myDayHash\[\'(.*?)\'\] = (.*?);", text)
print(dict(myDayHash))
```

Answer (score 1):

That variable is defined in the function's scope (not global). In other words you can't.

Comment: Maybe i can get array using parsing somehow?

Comment: Sure. regex is the way to go.